# How to send data from Arduino to Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, message, send

I went to a struggle. There are so many tutorials regarding this topic, but I cannot adapt any of those to my project.

What I want to do is simple:
User press the button in Android (Dialog opens, user enters numbeers, presses ok)
Arduino compares data and if it matches send one message to Android, if no - another.
Concept is this.

What I have so far is simple Arduino code

```
void loop() {
if (Serial.available() > 0) {  // if the data came
incomingByte = Serial.read(); // read byte
if(incomingByte == '0') {
   digitalWrite(LED, LOW);  // if 1, switch LED Off
   Serial.println("LED OFF. Press 1 to LED ON!");  // print message
}
if(incomingByte == '1') {
   digitalWrite(LED, HIGH); // if 0, switch LED on
   Serial.println("LED ON. Press 0 to LED OFF!");
   bluetoothSerial.write
}
}
```

I found great tutorial for sending data from Arduino to Android, but it's made in Thread mode and I cannot adopt it to my AsyncThread solution. This is the main problem :\

My Android AsyncThread code looks like that:

```
    private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  // UI thread
{
    private boolean ConnectSuccess = true; //if it's here, it's almost connected

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(ConnectedActivity.this, "Connecting...", "Please wait!!!");  //show a progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) //while the progress dialog is shown, the connection is done in background
    {

        try
        {
            if (btSocket == null || !isBtConnected)
            {
                myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();//get the mobile bluetooth device
                BluetoothDevice dispositivo = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);//connects to the device's address and checks if it's available
                btSocket = dispositivo.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);//create a RFCOMM (SPP) connection
                BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                btSocket.connect();//start connection
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            ConnectSuccess = false;//if the try failed, you can check the exception here
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) //after the doInBackground, it checks if everything went fine
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!ConnectSuccess)
        {
            Toast.makeText(ConnectedActivity.this, "Connection Failed. Is it a SPP Bluetooth? Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(ConnectedActivity.this, "Succeed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isBtConnected = true;
        }
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Solution from the tutorial:

```
 h = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                    sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                            // if end-of-line,
                        String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                        txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint);            // update TextView
                        btnOff.setEnabled(true);
                        btnOn.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                    break;
            }
        };
    };


private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, "...Data to send: " + message + "...");
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");
        }
    }
}
```

Full tutorial can be found here:
http://solderer.tv/data-transfer-between-android-and-arduino-via-bluetooth/

I can send data from Android to Arduino with no problem. But receiving it.. nope. Any suggestions?

EDITv2

Silly me. I've put handler and thread's code in my activity. And ran

```
                mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread();
                mConnectedThread.start();
```

in AsyncTask background task. I can see valid toast message now.
Tnx!

Comment: check https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/anrdroid-sendreceive-data-with-arduino-via-bluetooth-part-1/

Comment: if you would check the tutorial i've provided, its same code +- :) I just having trouble implementing reading part in Android, since im using asynctask to establish connection